# Django: records that have most matching words should come up higher in the result set

Tags: python, django

This is my first app/site. I am trying to implement a search option.

I have these to implement the search view:

```
def normalize_query(query_string,  findterms=re.compile(r'"([^"]+)"|(\S+)').findall, normspace=re.compile(r'\s{2,}').sub):
    return [normspace('',(t[0] or t[1]).strip()) for t in findterms(query_string)]

def get_query(query_string, search_fields):

    '''
    Returns a query, that is a combination of Q objects.
    That combination aims to search keywords within a model by testing the given search fields.
    '''

    query = None # Query to search for every search term
    terms = normalize_query(query_string)
    for term in terms:
        or_query = None # Query to search for a given term in each field
        for field_name in search_fields:
            q = Q(**{"%s__icontains" % field_name: term})
            if or_query is None:
                or_query = q
            else:
                or_query = or_query | q
        if query is None:
            query = or_query
        else:
            query = query | or_query
    return query

def search_doctor(request):
   query_string = ''
   found_entries = None
   query_string = request.POST.get('doctor', None).strip()
   if query_string:
       entry_query = get_query(query_string, ['full_name'])
       found_entries = User.objects.filter(entry_query, groups__name='Doctor') #.order_by('first_name')

   context = { 'query_string': entry_query, 
               'doctors': found_entries
             }
   #return redirect('health:doctors' )
   return render(request,'doctors_search_list.html', context )
```

It does search records but I am looking for a way to show records that have most matching search terms in them come up higher in the order.

Can anyone guide me.

Thank you.

Comment: Guiding can be done if you show an attempt and get an error. SO is not a coding on demand site with free labor at your disposal while you get paid for it from elsewhere. Moved to editing..end of triage review.

Comment: I am not getting paid for it. I am learning it. 
What am I supposed to do so that I come with error to you? You can add "Not for learning" on the site title so that beginners don't come here. 

I have no interest in typing a question that won't get answered. I did searching on SO and Google. But didn't find anything of this sort in case of Django. I Google before I come here because that is where whole world of information is. 


If you don't like helping just bug off. 

Thank you for whatever edit you did.

Comment: ... you just have to show effort in trying to solve it yourself first, which is likely to produce an error or two but shows the direction where you want to go or should not go to with the type of answer you are looking instead. We've all been there once or twice. As CoffeeBasedLifeform shows in his/her answer.. the answer is "uncertain" because your question is too broad... and thus (if lucky) will generate a ton of answers...but none could be the one you're looking for. So.. hold your horses and focus on the result you want to obtain.. "verbal discussion" or constructive result? Don't answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can order your results if you do seperate queries for each 'result order criteria' and then join the queries as lists.

Assume you want to query based on a search string. Then this would return exact matches before matches that simply started with the search string, followed by anthing that contains the search string:

```
def find_stuff(queryset, search_term):
    exact_match_qs = queryset.filter(name__exact=search_term)
    startsw_qs = queryset.exclude(pk__in=exact_match_qs).filter(name__startswith=search_term)
    qs = queryset.exclude(pk__in=startsw_qs).exclude(pk__in=exact_match_qs).filter(name__icontains=search_term)
    return list(exact_match_qs)+list(startsw_qs)+list(qs)
```

Obviously, this does not return a `QuerySet` object and does not fit your current `get_query' implementation.